# Request to add visual difference between blockquotes and code blocks

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

It has always irked my inner aesthetic nazi that code blocks are indistinguishable* from blockquotes at first glance. See [my recent answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/241823/setting-a-time-limit-for-a-transaction-in-mysql-innodb/241835#241835) for an example. I'm picturing something like this:
[image]

<sub>*Yes, I know that code is monospace and blockquotes are not.</sub>

Comment: An option to show/hide line numbers on code blocks would be nice too. Maybe highlighting? But highliting can get pretty offensive to the eyes. I like the colors on github, at least they are more easy to read.

Comment: @Coredump, we've talked about code highlighting in the past and decided to leave it off as detecting the language/syntax is very error prone without the user explicitly picking.

Comment: @Chris I would happily pick the language. Maybe as an option, part of the markup? But the markup here is really simple so maybe meh.

Comment: +1 I've wished for SU style blockquotes for a while now...

Comment: +1. I like the the simple, grey bar option, too. (I'd add another +1 for making me try to upvote the screenshot, instead of the question)

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if this feature request is to be implemented some day? tex.SE has something similar already - [blockquotes are enclosed by horizontal lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518), [code sniplets are not](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498). Although there is a [recent motion for syntax highlighting](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2717), the implementation of which would make the issue less pressing, it still would be very nice to have.

Comment: This would indeed clear up a lot of confusion between the two.

Comment: Another year has passed, yet nothing has changed and no authoritative response has been given. I've added a tag to the question. I *really* would like to see it happen - as 19 other Meta participants apparently would.

Comment: @syneticon-dj: If you use FF or Chrome then try stylish + [this small reskin I wrote](http://userstyles.org/styles/68486/serverfault). I know you shouldn't have to but ...

Answer (score 13):

In the true spirit of "better late than never"... I just pushed a change that will add a border to the blockquotes similar to what's proposed here, but a bit more lightweight:

[image]

This change applies to both Server Fault and its meta, and will be live as of rev 2014.5.21.1619.