# Questions with favourites tags: can you make the background darker?

Tags: feature-request, tags, design

On the Stack Overflow, it's easy to realize the questions with favourite tags:

[image]

But on the SF, the background is quite light:

[image]

What do you think?

Comment: Related http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1745 http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1285 and http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/tagged/design Apparently the design team has high contrast monitors and good eyesight. The look of the sight has been an outstanding "issue" for a long time, nothing has changed, when asked about it "they" have said it's on their list (along with all the other suggestions that have been ignored).

Comment: Or, it's because our designer is scared to touch the trilogy ...

Comment: @Zypher Fair enough, but don't say that "we're looking at it" or similarly misleading statements (not you personally; as a figure of speech). I'd disagree with "We're not changing it, evar", but it irks me when people say one thing and do another, just as bad as the "suggestion box" black hole.

Comment: @chris soory that was in humor. It is on the design teams list to eventually look at the trillogy

Comment: Yeah... That's the standard line of bull *stuff* we've been hearing for years now. This is why commitments only ever mean something when they have a date attached. =[

Answer (score 2):

The design team will eventually get round to looking at this I'm sure. Whilst waiting perhaps you'd like to have a go at [factoring this number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers#RSA-2048) which may turn out to take less time.

Alternatively you can use stylish in [FF](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) or [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) and [tweak the colour scheme](http://userstyles.org/styles/68486/serverfault) yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. Maybe you need to adjust your monitor. While the contrast isn't as great as that on SO it's still more than adequate to make it obvious.