# Please fix our design issues

Tags: discussion, design

There are a number of [design](/questions/tagged/design) issues that have been outstanding for (quite frankly) a ridiculous amount of time.

This morning (UTC) one of the [known design issues](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1745/change-style-of-links) contributed to a certain amount of tension that really wasn't necessary.

In the past excuses, have been put forward that the 'designer' was busy, well now there is more than one designer - how hard can it be ?

Comment: Laziness and complacency can be very difficult to overcome.

Comment: Can one really file bugs against developers?

Comment: Isn't meta.stackexchange.com designed to be a communication between the developers / mainainers?  As for why SE designers don't handle this issue or the other....well true that is not communicated very well...not even a list of the thing being considered and worked on.

Comment: @FalconMomot the feed for tag bug is monitored by the developers.

Comment: @Iain I know.  Filing a bug like this is kind of like relating a bug ticket to someone's resource allocation ticket in redmine.  However, you did get an upvote from me.

Comment: @mdpc No, this relates solely to SF and should therefore be raised here on the mSF - why would any non SF users be interested in for example the poor visibility of the links on the main SF site? SE even issued guidance to moderators in the [April Moderator News letter](http://moderator.stackexchange.com/2014/04/april-2014-newsletter/) regarding the relationship between mSE and child metas.

Comment: @Iain -- didn't know about the moderator news letter.  Interesting!

Comment: @mdpc Community Mods and other SE staff have also stated repeatedly on meta.SE that they monitor the site-specific metas.  So it's not necessary to post to meta.SE even if it's a borderline case (and this is clearly site-specific)

Comment: I'm perhaps confused as to who addresses the SE design issues.  Doesn't SE staff do this for all the SE sites?  or are making SE modifications left to the individual SE sites? how?

Comment: @Ward Here, for example, is a recent answer by SE valued associate #5 stating that they keep an eye on all metas: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231250/ability-to-move-questions-to-stackexchange-meta

Comment: @Ward (psst, you're talking to yourself)

Comment: @AndrewB  It's the only way I can be sure that someone's paying attention!

Comment: @Ward I just put it down to your age ;)

Comment: @Ward Kids today!

Answer (score 3):

More designers doesn't automatically mean they're all free to tackle a few years' worth of design backlog issues across multiple sites. There are other demands on their time and overall that's still one of the busiest teams we got.

Having said that, as we discussed over email, I'll be looking into the most annoying issues you pointed out. [One of them](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/1285/request-to-add-visual-difference-between-blockquotes-and-code-blocks) is already fixed as I write this. The rest will require more designer wrangling, but I'll see what I can do.

Y'all only got 12 questions tagged [design](/questions/tagged/design), so I'm gonna close with some of the most famous last words in software development... "it shouldn't be too hard". :)

Comment: If you drill down, then it's only 4 issues now that you have fixed the blockquotes. The only one that really matters is making links easier to see, people really do fail to notice them. Cheers

Comment: Anna I'm really tempted to put the bug tag back on this issue - people really do fail to notice links ... here's another one from today http://serverfault.com/questions/604757/why-a-sed-command-stop-my-log-file-to-be-written-to/604764?noredirect=1#comment716521_604764

Comment: @Iain Ack. I knew I was forgetting something... Sorry 'bout that. Fixed: http://meta.serverfault.com/a/6386/101854.